# Flutter Gradle Build Failed on Mobile

Tags: flutter, dart

I started my flutter journey yesterday. I have setup flutter required tools.
When I open project in VS Code and ran in Browser then It is working fine.
The problem is when I am running same code in mobile I am getting below error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

> Failed to transform kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.5.2.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=6, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject=public, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\Ak.gradle\caches\transforms-3\c940960e50601bb47697097bd1836bc5\transformed\jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.5.2.jar.
> > zip END header not found
> Failed to transform kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.2.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.5.2) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\Ak.gradle\caches\transforms-3\603da669cefc7e262274ae9bd7d51a7a\transformed\jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.2.jar.
> > zip END header not found
> Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\Ak.gradle\caches\transforms-3\c5e3755d369a342348422e6bb01320ab\transformed\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10.jar.
> > zip END header not found
> Failed to transform lifecycle-common-2.2.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.2.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\Ak.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.lifecycle\lifecycle-common\2.2.0\4ef09a745007778eef83b92f8f23987a8ea59496\lifecycle-common-2.2.0.jar.
> > zip END header not found
> Failed to transform core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\Ak.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.arch.core\core-common\2.1.0\b3152fc64428c9354344bd89848ecddc09b6f07e\core-common-2.1.0.jar.
> > zip END header not found
> Failed to transform collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\Ak.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.collection\collection\1.1.0\1f27220b47669781457de0d600849a5de0e89909\collection-1.1.0.jar.
> > zip END header not found
> Failed to transform annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=7, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\Ak.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.annotation\annotation\1.2.0\57136ff68ee784c6e19db34ed4a175338fadfde1\annotation-1.2.0.jar.
> > zip END header not found
> Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.7.10) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\Ak.gradle\caches\transforms-3\1d4fa5d5671987eb4ee34407afc7a401\transformed\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar.
> > zip END header not found

BUILD FAILED in 1m 58s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            119.5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Please guide me how to resolve this.

I tried gradle build and clean command.
I also tried deleting gradle directory.